# Elixir/Phoenix Ecto preload associations not working for has_many

Tags: associations, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, preload

I am getting crazy. Now working a half day on my problem and can't find the solution/error. Creating a chat, I got a chat model and a chat_user model which has a user model as a foreign key.

Chat has `has_many :chat_users, Test.Chat.ChatUser, foreign_key: :chat_id` as has many, and the chat_user has `belongs_to :user, Test.User` and `belongs_to :chat, Test.Chat.Chat`.

I am preloading the associations with:

```
  defp preload_associations(chat, params \\ nil) do
    Repo.preload(chat, [
     :chat_users
   ])
  end
```

The Error i get is: `** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42703 (undefined_column): column c0.user_id does not exist`

The table `chat_users` in the database has the field `user_id` with a foreign key. It seems to me, Ecto is searching for `user_id` in chat instead of `chat_user`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

EDIT: Models

```
defmodule Test.Chat.ChatItem do
@moduledoc false

use Test.Web, :model

schema "chats" do
  field :name, :string
  ...
  has_many :chat_users, Test.Chat.ChatUser, foreign_key: :chat_id
  timestamps()
end


defmodule Test.Chat.ChatUser do
use Test.Web, :model

schema "chat_users" do
  ...
  belongs_to :user, Test.User
  belongs_to :chat, Test.Chat.Chat
end
```

And

```
defmodule Test.User do
...
```

Comment: You better post your models here, it is easier to spot an error in models than in in-words description.

Comment: Try to remove `foreign_key: :chat_id` from `has_many` definition.

Comment: And... do you really want to preload chat_users, or you want to preload users instead?

Comment: Removing foreign-key caused `* (Ecto.QueryError) deps/ecto/lib/ecto/association.ex:495: field Test.Chat.ChatUser.chat_item_id in where does not exist in the schema in query`. And yes. I want to preload chat_users, the next step is to preload users from chat_users. chat_users has fields I need and users also. REST-Api, need all the stuff at once in the response.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found the error. Had nothing to do with my migration or the models. The problem was caused by some environment configurations. The script, which builds the dev and test database did not drop the test database, so it had no user_id in the chat_users table. The error occured with mix test inside the docker container, so finding the error was not easy. I am new to elixir and still hate the stacktrace, used to read some nice c# stacktrace ;)
But thanks for the help.

Comment: That's probably because you've run the migration, then changed it. In this case it is your responsibility to fix the mess. I do `MIX_ENV=test mix do ecto.drop, ecto.create, ecto.migrate`.